# Wrong mapping of key, value in python dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

For code below:

```
a = dict()
x = ['a','b','c']
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = ['p','q']
for zz in z:
    a[zz] = dict((xx,yy) for xx,yy in zip(x,(t for t in y)))
print a
```

I am getting:

```
{'q': {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, 'p': {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}}
```

But, the dictionary I am expecting is:

```
{'q': {'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5}, 'p': {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any logical error in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time through your `for` block, the `t for t in y` (which I assume was just an attempt to make something work when `y` alone didn't work?) is started over, so you're always going to get the first elements from the `y` list. One way to get it to keep its position each time through would be to turn it into an iterator:

```
y = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

While you're at it, you might as well turn the `(t for t in y)` back into simply `y`.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
a = dict()
x = ['a','b','c']
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
z = ['p','q']
for i, zz in enumerate(z):
    a[zz] = dict((xx,yy) for xx,yy in zip(x*(i+1),y))
print a
```

In the original code, the `zip(x, (t for t in y))` part will always cut the end off of the longer of the two lists.